# Zend Framework 1.11 with Doctrine 2 Integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

Could someone explain in detail how to integrate Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework 1.11?

Comment: There's no magic nor rocket science involved. Just make sure you initialize Doctrine in your bootstrap, and use it as you normally do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a great video by Jon Lebensold about integrating  D2 and ZF: [Unit Testing Doctrine 2](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/) - don't be misleaded by the title :)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a late inclusion but I just did this following the Zend webinar recording at http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000bSrG-webinar-zf-v-1-doctrine-v-2-20101214.flv (you need a (free) Zend account to view it).

Ralph Schindler also has the slides up here http://www.slideshare.net/ralphschindler/zend-framework-1-doctrine-2-6177485

If you're familiar with Doctrine2, you can probably skip the first half.

Answer (score 3):

There are **[several Github repositories](https://github.com/search?q=zf+doctrine&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1)** that show you how to do this.

Take a look at the source code and learn from it.

Apart from that, a **[simple Google search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=zend+framework+doctrine+2&qscrl=1)** yields plenty of results that should help get you on your way.

Answer (score 2):

Christian Soronellas has an tutorial: http://christian.soronellas.es/2010/12/19/zend-framework-and-doctrine-2/?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

There is nice ZF1+D2 project code example:
https://github.com/dynamicguy/zf1doctrine2

Answer (score 1):

you can download all project from

https://github.com/SpiffyJr/zfd2_tutorial

more info [in](http://www.spiffyjr.me/2010/11/17/zend-framework-1-11-doctrine-2-lets-play-nice-part-1/)

Comment: The github link you are referencing is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are still interested in, I just found a [Application Resource for Doctrine 2](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-application-resource-doctrine2).

Check out my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092006/is-it-possible-to-integrate-doctrine-2-with-zend-framework-1-1x/5094685#5094685)