# Is it possible to integrate Doctrine 2 with Zend Framework 1.1x?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'd really like to use and test Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework, but I don't where to start, and I don't know if both are compatible?

Do you have any feedback?

How could I integrate Doctrine 2 with Zend Framework 1.1x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001488/zend-framework-1-11-with-doctrine-2-integration

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of search, I found two implementations which of one I liked much because of its documentation and simplicity.

It is part of a Zend Framework extension called [Bgy library](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/), there is an [Application Resource](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-application-resource-doctrine2) to help bootstraping both Web application and CLI.

Comment: I'm looking for Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract implementations. What was the second implementation other than the Bgy library?

Comment: Both links are broken !

Answer (score 0):

There are several resources which will help you get started:

- [Bisna library](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2)
- [Cob library](https://github.com/cobbweb/Cob-ZendFramework-Doctrine2)
- [2-part series on integration](http://www.spiffyjr.me/2010/11/17/zend-framework-1-11-doctrine-2-lets-play-nice-part-1/)
- A [Doctrine 2 blog post](http://www.cobbweb.me/2010/11/integrate-doctrine-2-zend-framework-application/) I wrote myself on fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the excellent ZendCast: http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/