# set isolation level via PDO or Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract?

Tags: php, pdo, zend-db

Does there is way to set isolation level independently to concrete database driver in php?
Looks like there is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure there is a way to do such a thing with Zend_Db. The manual says that `setTransactionIsolationLevel()` can be used only with the [Microsoft SQL Server adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.sqlsrv).

> You can use setTransactionIsolationLevel() to set isolation level for
>   current connection. The value can be SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED,
>   SQLSRV_TXN_READ_COMMITTED, SQLSRV_TXN_REPEATABLE_READ,
>   SQLSRV_TXN_SNAPSHOT or SQLSRV_TXN_SERIALIZABLE.

It doesn't seem that the Zend_Db API implements a way to manage transaction isolation levels, the only way would be to write your own SQL statements and execute them according the the PDO driver you are using.

I would recommend you instead to use a better database abstraction layer such as [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/) (really powerful). Then you would be able to do it this way:

> The `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` also has methods to control the
>   transaction isolation level as supported by the underlying database.
>   **`Connection#setTransactionIsolation($level)`** and
>   **`Connection#getTransactionIsolation()`** can be used for that purpose. The
>   possible isolation levels are represented by the following constants:

```
<?php
Connection::TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
Connection::TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
Connection::TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Connection::TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001488/zend-framework-1-11-with-doctrine-2-integration) to know how to integrate Doctrine with ZF and [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#transactions) for more information about transaction management using Doctrine.